# Black Holes to an outside observer

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, observers, event-horizon

If an object were to fall into a black hole, would the inability of light escaping cause that object to stand still from an outside observer's perspective?
If not, then would the bent spacetime cause that object to only slowly fall from an outside observers perspective?

Comment: You're on the right track. Take a look at some of the existing [black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-holes)
 questions, especially those that mention time dilation.

Comment: The latter statement is correct.